# the methods are called in reverse

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

in the below code, when the `btnDiscoverListener` is called, the "`else`" statement executes and "`btAdapter.startDiscovery();`" then "`getBTDeviceExtras();`" are called.
in "`btAdapter.startDiscovery()`" it causes the broadcast receiver to recieve notification regarding the initiation of discovering the neigbouring devices,
and if a neigbouring device found, the broadcast receiever will go into "`BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND`".

i expected when "`btnDiscoverListener`" was called, "`getBTDeviceExtras()`" would not be executed till "`btAdapter.startDiscovery()`;" completely finishes!!
but as you see in the output posted below, "`getBTDeviceExtras()`" was called first.

can anyone explain how and why that is happeneing.

**Code**:

```
private OnClickListener btnDiscoverListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            return;
        } else {
            btAdapter.startDiscovery();
            getBTDeviceExtras();
        }
    }
};

private void getBTDeviceExtras() {
    Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("getBTDeviceExtras", "called."));

    if (this.stateExtDevice != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("getBTDeviceExtras", "called1."));
        adapter.add(this.stateExtDevice.getName()+"\n"+this.stateExtDevice.getAddress()+"\n"+this.stateExtDevice.getBondState()
                +"\n"+this.stateExtDevice.getType()+"\n"+this.stateExtDevice.getUuids());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("getBTDeviceExtras", "called2."));
        tvStatus.setText("BT-Receiver received not notifications");
    }
}
```

**Code**:

```
08-25 10:54:14.305: D/MainActivity(2624): -> getBTDeviceExtras:called.
08-25 10:54:14.315: D/MainActivity(2624): -> getBTDeviceExtras:called2.
08-25 10:54:14.325: D/MainActivity(2624): -> onReceive:BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED
08-25 10:54:15.155: D/MainActivity(2624): -> onReceive:BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND
08-25 10:54:27.155: D/MainActivity(2624): -> onReceive:BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
```

Comment: The `startDiscovery()`is asynchronus, meaning that it'll just call the `startDiscovery()` and then it'll run in the background. You need to wait for it to finish somehow.

Comment: @Detilium can u please tell me how did u know that startdiscovery is a asnchronous??

Comment: Fomr [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184420/bluetooth-on-android-startdiscovery-not-working-cannot-scan-devices) SO thread (Answer no. 1) EDIT: [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery())

Answer (score 2):

As per android documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

public boolean startDiscovery ()

Added in API level 5
Start the remote device discovery process.

The discovery process usually involves an inquiry scan of about 12 seconds, followed by a page scan of each new device to retrieve its Bluetooth name.

This is an asynchronous call, it will return immediately. Register for ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED and ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED intents to determine exactly when the discovery starts and completes. Register for ACTION_FOUND to be notified as remote Bluetooth devices are found.

Device discovery is a heavyweight procedure. New connections to remote Bluetooth devices should not be attempted while discovery is in progress, and existing connections will experience limited bandwidth and high latency. Use cancelDiscovery() to cancel an ongoing discovery. Discovery is not managed by the Activity, but is run as a system service, so an application should always call cancelDiscovery() even if it did not directly request a discovery, just to be sure.

Call your getBTDeviceExtras() method when discovery is finished.